# Autohotkey ComObjActive Outlook wrong encoding of umlauts

Tags: outlook, character-encoding, autohotkey

Currently i use Autohotkey to prefill Emails with Text and Attachments.

```
tml_body=
  (
  <html>
    <body>

      test

    </body>
  </html>
  )

m := ComObjActive("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
m.Subject := "subject with umlauts äüö "
m.To := "foo@bar.com"
m.CC := "foo@bar.com"
m.HTMLBody := html_body
m.Display
;m.attachments.add("filepath")

WinWait Untitled - Message (HTML)
WinActivate Untitled - Message (HTML)
```

Using this script opens a new outlook mail with the following subject "subject with umlauts Ã¤Ã¼Ã¶ "
In the hmtlbody something like `&uuml;` works but not in the subject.

How can i set or encode a subject to display special characters / umlauts correctly?

Comment: Try saving the code in UTF-8 format. Paste the code in a Notepad document and choose File --> Save As... --> Encoding --> UTF-8.

Comment: wow it did the job. thanks ...But it is still strange for me. I edited the file in with Atom and UTF-8 was selected, but the subject was still wrong. After opening the File in Notepad++ and selecting `UTF-8` instead of `UTF-8 ohne BOM` and saving it again it worked ... After editing something in Atom and saving it there it still was fine. Sometimes i really hate and don't understand character encoding -.-

Comment: @user3419297 add your response as an answer if you want and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the code in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) format.

e.g.

- In Notepad choose File --> Save As... --> Encoding --> UTF-8
- in Notepad++ choose Encoding --> Encode in UTF-8