# "is lower" not working for strings containing exotic characters

Tags: string, autohotkey

I have a code part that checks if a string is all lower-case or not. If it is, it gives me the first and last characters as abbreviation. If not, it gives me the upper-case parts as an abbreviation.

```
if Hotstring is lower
    {
    ShortString := SubStr(Hotstring,1,1) . SubStr(Hotstring,0)
    }else{
    ShortString := RegExReplace(Hotstring, "[a-záéiíóöőúüű ]", "")
    StringLower,ShortString, ShortString
    }
```

**The problem:**
If my input string contains mid-european characters, the string is not recognized properly as lower-case.

Comment: Try **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590027/autohotkey-comobjactive-outlook-wrong-encoding-of-umlauts/47592273#47592273)**.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but i need a solution that works reliably for any users in any apps.

Comment: I have created workaround now, that is reliable… but IstenFia Symby knows a built ilyen switch …. LényElmélet mente know.: testString := RegExReplace(Hotstring, "[áéiíóöőúüű]", "a")
  if testString is lower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A breakaway from the *legacy syntax*, which has been eliminated in AutoHotkey v2, almost always provides better solutions.
2. Read about **POSIX named sets** and **`(*UCP)`** [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm).

The following's been tested to work:

```
If RegExMatch(Hotstring, "(*UCP)^[[:lower:] ]+$")   
    ; or just "(*UCP)^[[:lower:]]+$" if you want to stick with the exact definition of the "lower" type
    ShortString := SubStr(Hotstring, 1, 1) SubStr(Hotstring, 0)
Else
    ShortString := Format("{:L}", RegExReplace(Hotstring, "(*UCP)[[:lower:] ]+"))
```

A functionally identical, yet more concise alternative:

```
ShortString := Hotstring ~= "(*UCP)^[\p{Ll} ]+$" 
               ? SubStr(Hotstring, 1, 1) SubStr(Hotstring, 0)
               : Format("{:L}", RegExReplace(Hotstring, "(*UCP)[\p{Ll} ]+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created workaround for myself, that first transforms the special letters into a simple lcap letter - only to see if the full string is lcap or not.
after this check, i continue to work with the original string, not the transformed.
**testString := RegExReplace(Hotstring, "[áéiíóöőúüű]", "a")**

```
testString := RegExReplace(Hotstring, "[áéiíóöőúüű]", "a")
        if testString is lower
        {
        ShortString := SubStr(Hotstring,1,1) . SubStr(Hotstring,0)
        }else{
        ShortString := RegExReplace(Hotstring, "[a-záéiíóöőúüű ]", "")
        StringLower,ShortString, ShortString
        }
```

IF some of you know of a simple switch/option that allows the proper inbuilt recognition of these characters as high/low, please post it.
Until then, use my workaround.